# Consume one message per time in Netcore and Kafka

Tags: .net-core, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm trying to making a Consumer Kafka using NET CORE 2.1, this consumer should read one message compare timestamp and commit or not, so this consumer can stay on same message until this validation is true. See my code:

```
while(true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var cr = consumer.Consume(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(4000));
                            if (cr == null)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Exiting ... no messages to process");
                                break;
                            }

                            double totalSeconds = (DateTime.Now - cr.Timestamp.UtcDateTime).TotalSeconds;

                            Console.WriteLine($"TotalSeconds = {totalSeconds} , Resume = {resumeTimeSeconds}");
                            if (totalSeconds > resumeTimeSeconds)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Message = {cr.Value}");
                                consumer.Commit();
                            }else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Skipping... {cr.Value}");
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (ConsumeException e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Error occured: {e.Error.Reason}");
                        }
                    }
```

So, I have 10 messages in my topic and LAG is 2. I want to the next message is called only if i Commit() the previous message, but the consumer.Consume() method always call the next message.

Comment: Did you set  enable.auto.commit to false for your consumer? What the value of your max.poll.records also? Could you share more information regarding your consumer properties?

Comment: My enabled.auto.commit is false and Don't exist max.poll.records in .net driver

Answer (score 0):

The consumer commit comes into play only when your consumer start ( or recover from a crash). Your consumer will internally keep track of the  last received offset for each partition.

What you can do is maybe use seek() to get back to the previous offset you just tried to process, and then retry.

Yannick

Comment: I don't know if seek() is a solution because I didn't change the offset, i think netcore driver is retriving a buffer of records, not only one.

Comment: There is a simple way to check if this is  a records buffered behavior or not, just run your consumer without any commit, in the meantime send a text message using a producer, wait to receive it with your consumer, then send another message with the producer, you'll see that the next attempt to poll() will get the new message, meaning that it's consumer internal offset.
Pretty sure seek() would help in your case, you save the record offset, you try to process it, if you fail, you seek(TopicPartition, yourSavedOffset) and retry